# How to build a monthly subscription with Stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am working with Stripe subscription and I don't want to create different plans with xy users included but set the price simple to 10$ per user per month. See the pricing at https://www.box.com/en_GB/pricing/ to get an idea what I mean.

How can i realize that subscription behavior in Stripe? Do I need to create an own plan for every count of users? (eg. oneuserplan 10$, twouserplan 20$, threeuserplan 30$,.....)

Or can I somehow multiply the 10$/month base subscription with with the count of users?

Comment: Read Stripe's documentation and notice the Quantity field.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a quantity field in [stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#create_subscription)

> The quantity you'd like to apply to the subscription you're creating.
>   For example, if your plan is $10/user/month, and your customer has 5
>   users, you could pass 5 as the quantity to have the customer charged
>   $50 (5 x $10) monthly....